# How to capture http messages from Request Node library with Fiddler

Tags: node.js, fiddler

Regular client initiated requests to the node server are captured fine in Fiddler. However, requests sent from node to a web service are not captured. It did not help to pass in config for proxy (127.0.0.1:8888) to the request method. How can I route the request messages through Fiddler?

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

request.get(webserviceURL, { "auth" : {"user": "user", "pass" = "pass", sendImmediately: true },
"proxy" : { "host" : "127.0.0.1", "port" : 8888 }},
function (error, response) { console.log( "response received" );
});
```

Request repo: https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: Setting the proxy on the request object *should* be all you need to do, but I don't see a "proxy" property in the docs? http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: I'm using the third-party request package. Link in description.

Comment: Poking around in the source, it seems to imply that the syntax would be "hostname" rather than "host"? Or you could define proxy as the string "http://127.0.0.1:8888" rather than as an object?

Comment: Changing "host" to "hostname" did not help. Can you get it working?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just tried to do this myself (using Fiddler and the request library from npm). Here's how I got it working:

```
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0'; // Ignore 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' authorization error

// Issue the request
request(
{
    method: "GET",
    uri: "https://secure.somewebsite.com/",
    proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:8888" // Note the fully-qualified path to Fiddler proxy. No "https" is required, even for https connections to outside.
},
function(err, response, body) {
    console.log("done");
});
```

This is with Fiddler2 using the default port and proxy options (and no proxy authentication).

Comment: Thanks a lot. the setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED really helps. Without it, https request won't work for me. Just curious, what does this environment variable mean?

Comment: I believe it allows Node to use self-signed SSL certificates, which would normally be a security risk, but in this case it's what you want :)

Answer (score 5):

Fiddler works by setting your "Internet Options" (from start menu) "Connections" > "LAN Settings" > "Proxy Server" to its port, thus making all HTTP traffic (clients which **obey** this setting) go through it.

You should point your node.js client lib  to use a proxy, the settings are written in that options dialog after you start Fiddler.

Comment: Did you edit your question or did I get a REAL blackout and missed that part in your code example? LOL

Comment: Although proxy is implicitly mentioned in the first post, this one solved the problem for me by drawing my attention more explicitly. Thanks @poni.

Answer (score 4):

The proxy option should be a full url, like this:

```
proxy : "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this on an ad-hoc basis, without changing your code, you can use environment variables.

Request respects:

- HTTP_PROXY
- HTTPS_PROXY
- NO_PROXY

So, to proxy just set these in your console before running your process.

For example, to setup http and https proxy use:

```
set HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:8888"
set HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:8888"
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

The latter line stops issues with SSL through the fiddler proxy.

Comment: For me, on Windows 10, the first 2 lines did not work. It works without the quotes..

Answer (score 0):

I've been wanting the same... an equivalent of the `Network` tab in chrome DevTools, only for Nodejs.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear as though one exists.  I don't have Fiddler on macos, so this is how I went about stubbing the `require('http')` methods to log and pass though.  Leaving this here in case I need it again or someone else finds it helpful.  You can turn it on by attaching a debugger and `require('filename')()` the file containing this script.

```js
module.exports = () => {
    const http = require('http');
    http._request = http.request;

    global.DO_LOG_AJAX = true;
    const log = str => {
        if (global.DO_LOG_AJAX) {
            console.debug(str);
        }
    };

    const flushLog = (requestLines, responseLines) => {
        if (global.DO_LOG_AJAX) {
            log([
                '----------------Begin Request-----------------------------------',
                ...requestLines,
                '----------------End Request / Begin Response--------------------',
                ...responseLines,
                '----------------End Reponse-------------------------------------',
            ].join('\n'));
        }
    };

    let write;
    let end;
    http.request = (...requestParams) => {
        const req = http._request(...requestParams);
        const { method, path, headers, host, port } = requestParams[0];
        const requestLogLines = [];
        requestLogLines.push(`${method} ${path}`);
        requestLogLines.push(`Host: ${host}:${port}`);
        for (const header of Object.keys(headers)) {
            requestLogLines.push(`${header}: ${headers[header]}`);
        }
        write = write || req.write;
        end = end || req.end;

        req.on('error', err => {
            log({ err });
        });

        req._write = write;
        req._end = end;
        const requestBody = [];
        req.write = (...writeParams) => {
            requestBody.push(writeParams[0].toString());
            return req._write(...writeParams);
        };
        req.end = (...endParams) => {
            if (endParams[0]) {
                requestBody.push(endParams[0].toString());
            }
            requestLogLines.push('');
            requestLogLines.push(requestBody.join(''));
            return req._end(...endParams);
        };

        const responseLogLines = [];
        req.once('response', response => {
            const responseBody = [];
            responseLogLines.push(`${response.statusCode} ${response.statusMessage}`);
            for (const header of Object.keys(response.headers)) {
                responseLogLines.push(`${header}: ${response.headers[header]}`);
            }
            const onData = chunk => {
                responseBody.push(chunk.toString());
            };
            const onClose = err => {
                responseLogLines.push('');
                responseLogLines.push(responseBody.join(''));
                responseLogLines.push('');
                responseLogLines.push(`--- ERROR --- ${err.toString()}`);
                flushLog(requestLogLines, responseLogLines);
                req.removeListener('data', onData);
            };
            const onEnd = () => {
                responseLogLines.push('');
                responseLogLines.push(responseBody.join(''));
                flushLog(requestLogLines, responseLogLines);
                req.removeListener('data', onData);
            };
            response.on('data', onData);
            response.once('close', onClose);
            response.once('end', onEnd);
        });

        return req;
    };
};
```