# Send soap message with nodejs to WSDL service

Tags: java, node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have deployed a wsdl service.
[image: WSDL service]

As you can see, I have a unique method "hola". It returns the string "Hello World". To start, the method doesn't have parameters. When it works I want to add one.

The soap message I send with nodejs. I'm using "soap" module.
The WSDL service is running in port 8080 and the message I'm sending from 3000.

This is the way I'm sending it.
[image: Message]

Then, I get a NullPointerException of QNameMap class.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.QNameMap.getEntry(QNameMap.java:462)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.QNameMap.get(QNameMap.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.PayloadQNameBasedDispatcher.getEndpointMethodHandler(PayloadQNameBasedDispatcher.java:79)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:559)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:518)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:503)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:400)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to implement a method with a parameter (string) and I got the same error.

With SoapUI I can send a message and  it works properly. 
[image]

I add all the information I get after I send the message. The body message is in the end.

```
{ _readableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: true,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: true,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function], [Function], [Function] ],
     readable: [Function],
     close: [ [Function], [Function] ],
     data: [Function],
     error: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: null,
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function],
        close: [Object],
        agentRemove: [Function],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Object],
        connect: undefined },
     _maxListeners: 0,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     onend: null,
     destroyed: true,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 4897,
     _bytesDispatched: 522,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/helloworld/HelloWorld',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /helloworld/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: node-soap/0.7.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: none\r\nAccept-Charset: utf-8\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nContent-Length: 208\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nSOAPAction: ""\r\n\r\n',
        _headerSent: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     ondata: null,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  connection: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: null,
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function],
        close: [Object],
        agentRemove: [Function],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Object],
        connect: undefined },
     _maxListeners: 0,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     onend: null,
     destroyed: true,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 4897,
     _bytesDispatched: 522,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/helloworld/HelloWorld',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /helloworld/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: node-soap/0.7.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: none\r\nAccept-Charset: utf-8\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nContent-Length: 208\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nSOAPAction: ""\r\n\r\n',
        _headerSent: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     ondata: null,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: true,
  headers: 
   { server: 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
     'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=utf-8',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     date: 'Sat, 21 Feb 2015 10:36:50 GMT',
     connection: 'close' },
  trailers: {},
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  url: '',
  method: null,
  statusCode: 500,
  client: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: null,
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function],
        close: [Object],
        agentRemove: [Function],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Object],
        connect: undefined },
     _maxListeners: 0,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     onend: null,
     destroyed: true,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 4897,
     _bytesDispatched: 522,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/helloworld/HelloWorld',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /helloworld/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: node-soap/0.7.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: none\r\nAccept-Charset: utf-8\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nContent-Length: 208\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nSOAPAction: ""\r\n\r\n',
        _headerSent: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     ondata: null,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1 },
  _consuming: true,
  _dumped: false,
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  upgrade: false,
  req: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: 
      { socket: [Object],
        response: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        drain: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _hangupClose: false,
     socket: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 0,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        onend: null,
        destroyed: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bytesRead: 4897,
        _bytesDispatched: 522,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        ondata: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1 },
     connection: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 0,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        onend: null,
        destroyed: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bytesRead: 4897,
        _bytesDispatched: 522,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        ondata: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1 },
     agent: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        options: {},
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        maxSockets: 5,
        createConnection: [Function] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/helloworld/HelloWorld',
     _headers: 
      { 'user-agent': 'node-soap/0.7.0',
        accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-encoding': 'none',
        'accept-charset': 'utf-8',
        connection: 'close',
        host: 'localhost:8080',
        'content-length': 208,
        'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        soapaction: '""' },
     _headerNames: 
      { 'user-agent': 'User-Agent',
        accept: 'Accept',
        'accept-encoding': 'Accept-Encoding',
        'accept-charset': 'Accept-Charset',
        connection: 'Connection',
        host: 'Host',
        'content-length': 'Content-Length',
        'content-type': 'Content-Type',
        soapaction: 'SOAPAction' },
     _header: 'POST /helloworld/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: node-soap/0.7.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: none\r\nAccept-Charset: utf-8\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nContent-Length: 208\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nSOAPAction: ""\r\n\r\n',
     _headerSent: true,
     parser: null,
     res: [Circular] },
  pipe: [Function],
  addListener: [Function],
  on: [Function],
  pause: [Function],
  resume: [Function],
  read: [Function],
  request: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: 
      { error: [Object],
        complete: [Function],
        pipe: [Function],
        end: [Object],
        data: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     callback: [Function],
     uri: 
      { protocol: 'http:',
        slashes: true,
        auth: null,
        host: 'localhost:8080',
        port: '8080',
        hostname: 'localhost',
        hash: null,
        search: null,
        query: null,
        pathname: '/helloworld/HelloWorld',
        path: '/helloworld/HelloWorld',
        href: 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/HelloWorld' },
     method: 'POST',
     headers: 
      { 'User-Agent': 'node-soap/0.7.0',
        Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
        Connection: 'close',
        Host: 'localhost:8080',
        'Content-Length': 0,
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        SOAPAction: '""' },
     readable: true,
     writable: true,
     explicitMethod: true,
     setHeader: [Function],
     hasHeader: [Function],
     getHeader: [Function],
     removeHeader: [Function],
     localAddress: undefined,
     qsLib: { stringify: [Function], parse: [Function] },
     pool: {},
     dests: [],
     __isRequestRequest: true,
     _callback: [Function],
     proxy: null,
     tunnel: undefined,
     _redirectsFollowed: 0,
     maxRedirects: 10,
     allowRedirect: [Function],
     followRedirects: true,
     followAllRedirects: false,
     redirects: [],
     setHost: false,
     originalCookieHeader: undefined,
     _disableCookies: true,
     _jar: undefined,
     port: '8080',
     host: 'localhost',
     path: '/helloworld/HelloWorld',
     _auth: 
      { hasAuth: false,
        sentAuth: false,
        bearerToken: null,
        user: null,
        pass: null },
     httpModule: 
      { parsers: [Object],
        STATUS_CODES: [Object],
        IncomingMessage: [Object],
        OutgoingMessage: [Object],
        ServerResponse: [Object],
        Agent: [Object],
        globalAgent: [Object],
        ClientRequest: [Object],
        request: [Function],
        get: [Function],
        Server: [Object],
        createServer: [Function],
        _connectionListener: [Function: connectionListener],
        Client: [Function: deprecated],
        createClient: [Function: deprecated] },
     agentClass: { [Function: Agent] super_: [Object], defaultMaxSockets: 5 },
     agent: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        options: {},
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        maxSockets: 5,
        createConnection: [Function] },
     _started: true,
     href: 'http://localhost:8080/helloworld/HelloWorld',
     req: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/helloworld/HelloWorld',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /helloworld/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: node-soap/0.7.0\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: none\r\nAccept-Charset: utf-8\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nContent-Length: 208\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nSOAPAction: ""\r\n\r\n',
        _headerSent: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     ntick: true,
     response: [Circular],
     originalHost: 'localhost:8080',
     originalHostHeaderName: 'Host',
     _destdata: true,
     _ended: true,
     _callbackCalled: true },
  toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
  caseless: 
   { dict: 
      { server: 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
        'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=utf-8',
        'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
        date: 'Sat, 21 Feb 2015 10:36:50 GMT',
        connection: 'close' } },
  body: '<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:Fault xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>ns2:Server</faultcode><faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring><detail><ns2:exception xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/" class="java.lang.NullPointerException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false"><ns2:stackTrace><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.util.QNameMap" file="QNameMap.java" line="462" method="getEntry"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.util.QNameMap" file="QNameMap.java" line="135" method="get"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.PayloadQNameBasedDispatcher" file="PayloadQNameBasedDispatcher.java" line="79" method="getEndpointMethodHandler"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube" file="SEIInvokerTube.java" line="72" method="processRequest"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="559" method="__doRun"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="518" method="_doRun"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="503" method="doRun"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="400" method="runSync"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="226" method="process"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="375" method="handle"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="175" method="handle"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="134" method="handle"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="159" method="doPost"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet" file="WSServlet.java" line="49" method="doPost"/><ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="647" method="service"/><ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="728" method="service"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="305" method="internalDoFilter"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="210" method="doFilter"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter" file="WsFilter.java" line="51" method="doFilter"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="243" method="internalDoFilter"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="210" method="doFilter"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve" file="StandardWrapperValve.java" line="222" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve" file="StandardContextValve.java" line="123" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase" file="AuthenticatorBase.java" line="502" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve" file="StandardHostValve.java" line="171" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" file="ErrorReportValve.java" line="100" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" file="AccessLogValve.java" line="953" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve" file="StandardEngineValve.java" line="118" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter" file="CoyoteAdapter.java" line="408" method="service"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor" file="AbstractHttp11Processor.java" line="1041" method="process"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler" file="AbstractProtocol.java" line="603" method="process"/><ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor" file="JIoEndpoint.java" line="310" method="run"/><ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor" line="unknown" method="runWorker"/><ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker" line="unknown" method="run"/><ns2:frame class="java.lang.Thread" line="unknown" method="run"/></ns2:stackTrace></ns2:exception></detail></ns2:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>' }
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong.

I tried this:

```
request(
{

    method: "POST",
    uri: "http://localhost:8080/helloworld/",

},
function(err, response, body) {
    console.log("err");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("response");
    console.log(response);
    console.log("body");
    console.log(body);
});
```

And I have changed the uri(because it doesn't work): http://localhost:8080/, http://localhost:8080/helloworld/HelloWorld?wsdl , but I fail to get the message.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you see the payload being sent from your node app? What does it look like?

Comment: This looks like the response from the server. Where's the payload sent TO the soap endpoint from NodeJS?

Comment: I'm trying to get the message, but do not know how to do. It does not appear in the Firefox or Chrome console. @JamieDixon

Comment: Consider setting up fiddler and your env so that fiddler picks up your nodejs http calls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383351/how-to-capture-http-messages-from-request-node-library-with-fiddler

Comment: I tried with fidder but I don't get response (I added the code in the question). In fact, I have used http://www.telerik.com/fiddler, but something is happening. I'm sorry to be so bad at this.@JamieDixon

Comment: I have used this webservice and the code works:http://oracle-base.com/webservices/server.php?wsdl. So I believe, my problem is in my WSDL.